# Rings of Cosets: Multiplication table for $S/I$

Tags: abstract-algebra

We are given,

$\hspace{100pt}$$S=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        0 & c \\
        \end{bmatrix} \middle| a\in \mathbb{Z}_4 \text{ and } b,c=[0]_4 \text{ or } [2]_4\right\}
$

$\hspace{128pt}I=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & b \\
        0 & c \\
        \end{bmatrix}\middle|b,c=[0]_4 \text{ or } [2]_4\right\}
$

and then asked to make a multiplication table of $S/I$.

I just wanted to make sure I was right in saying that

$\hspace{100pt}$$S/I=\left\{I+\begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        0 & c \\
        \end{bmatrix} \middle| a\in \mathbb{Z}_4 \text{ and } b,c=[0]_4 \text{ or } [2]_4\right\}
$

has 16 elements, so when I do the multiplication table, it will be a 16 $\times$ 16 table.

Answer (score 2):

No, $S/I$ does not have $16$ elements. Let $R=\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$. Hint, if $2\mid b,d$ then:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & d\end{pmatrix}\equiv \begin{pmatrix}a & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\mod{\begin{pmatrix}0 & 2R \\ 0 & 2R\end{pmatrix}}.$$

So the only thing that matters for representatives is the $a$ component.

(In fact $S$ itself has $16$ elements, so any nontrivial quotient must have strictly less.)

Answer (score 1):

Observe your ideal identifies any two matrices $$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}a'&b'\\0&c'\end{pmatrix}$$ whenever $a-a'=0$.